# fractal microscope simulator

Tags: imaging, fractals

I've done work on software used for controlling imaging hardware, such as microscopes, that are sometimes hard to get time on.  This means it is difficult to test out new/different algorithms which would require access to the instrument.  I'd like to create a synthetic instrument that could be used for some of these testing purposes, and I was thinking of using some kind of fractal image generation to create the synthetic images.  The key would be to be able to generate features at many different 'magnifications' and locations in some sort of deterministic manner.  This is because some of the algorithms being tested may need to pan/zoom and relocate previously 'imaged' areas.  Onto these base images I can then apply whatever instrument 'defects' are appropriate (focus, noise, saturation, etc.).

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to select/implement a good fractal algorithm for the base image.  Any help would be appreciated.  Preferably it would have the following qualities:

1. Be fast at rendering new image areas.
2. Fairly wide 'feature' coverage at as many locations and scales as possible.
3. Be deterministic (but initialized from random starting parameters).
4. Ability to tune to make images look more like 'real' images.

Item 2 is important, for example a mandelbrot set, with its large smooth/empty regions, might not be good since the software controlling the synthetic scope might fall into one of these areas.

So far I've thought of using something like a mandelbrot, but randomly shifting/rotating/scaling and merging two or more fractal sets to get more complete 'feature' coverage.

I've also seen images of the fractal flame algorithms and they seem to generate images that might be useful (and nice to look at).

Finally, I've thought of using some sort of paused particle simulation run to generate images that are more cell-like (my current imaging target), but I'm not sure if this approach can be made to work with the other requirements.

Edit:
@Jeffrey - So it sounds like some kind of terrain generation might be the way to go, as long as I have complete control over the PSRNG.  Perhaps I can use some stored initial seed + x position + y position to generate my random numbers?  But then I am unsure of how to consistently generate the terrains across scales, except, as you mentioned, to create the base terrain at the coursest scale, and at certain pre-determined 'magnifications' add new deterministic pseudo-random variations to this base.  I'd also have to be careful about when to generate the next level of terrain, since if I'm too aggressive I'd have to generate and integrate the results appropriately for display at the coarser level... This is why I initially was leaning toward a more 'traditional' fractal, since this integration from finer scales would be handled more implicitly (I think).

Comment: I am not really confident in what you want to achieve. Do you want to validate your software for a microscope or make a "virtual" microscope for teaching/demonstration?

Comment: I want to evaluate software algorithms to X degree of certainty, let's say 90%, before using precious actual instrument time to make sure it works IRL.  When it comes to modifying the base images to simulate microscope effects, such as out-of-focus, inexact movements, camera noise, I am a lot more confident as I've dealt with all these before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind a fractal terrain creation algorithm is to build the image at each scale separately. For a landscape it's easy: just make a small array of height values, and set them randomly. Then scale it up to a larger array, averaging the values so that the contour is smooth, and then add small random amounts to those values. Then scale it up, etc. The original small bumps have become mountains, and they are filled with complex terrain.

There are two particular difficulties with the problem posed here, though. First, you don't want to store any of these values, since it would be potentially huge. Secondly, the features at each scale are of a different kind than the features at other scales.

These problems are not insurmountable.

Basically, you would divide the image up into a grid, and using deterministic psedorandom numbers establish the key features of each square in the grid. For example, each square could have a certain density of cell types.

At the next level of magnification, subdivide each square into another grid, apply a gradiant of values across the grid that is based on the values of the containing square and its surrounding squares. Then apply pseudorandom variations to that seeded with the containing square's grid coordinates. For the random seed, always use the coordinates of the immediately containing square of the subdivision under consideration regardless of where the image is cropped, in order to ensure that it is recreated correctly accross multiple runs.

At some level of magnification the random values go from being densities of paticles types to particle locations. Then for each particle, there are partical features. Then features on those features.

Although arbitrary left/right and up/down scrolling will be desired, the image at all levels of magnification above the current scene will have to be calculated each time the frame is shifted to ensure that all necessary features are included. This way the image can be scrolled from one cell to another without loss of consistancy. Partical simulations can be used to ensure that cells or cell features don't overlap. This could be done in a repeatable, deterministic manner.

And don't forget to apply a smoothing gradient based on averages of surrounding squares at higher levels before adding in the random variations. Otherwise, the abrupt changes will make the squares themselves appear in the images!

This answer is somewhat rambling and probably confusing, but that is best I can explain it right now. I hope it helps!

Comment: no that's helpful, it gets closer to what I was thinking as one possible solution.  You are right, I was wondering if a random scene generation and storing the results would be the way to go... this might work depending on how long things were running (how large the stored dataset grew), but even better is storing the seeds used for a psuedo-random scene generator, that way I can use something like a particle-simulator to create more 'realistic' looking images and be able to recreate areas on the fly.

Comment: any idea on what is currently feasible in terms of number of particles in a quick particle simulation?  The image types I currently look at are optical microscope images, and a full dataset might have 4 million cells.  So is a quick (in terms of time-scale) n-body simulation of 4 million points 'fast' these days?

Comment: @user476615 - A simulation of 4 million particles isn't going to be quick. And if the density of particles across the entire image is not going to have any breaks, then the locations cannot be calculated without reference to the location of all other particles in the entire system. Perhaps the cell locations could be pre-calculated and stored. Then only the small features would be calculated on the fly, and those could be done using only local, smaller data sets.